# NoClassDefFoundError from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, noclassdeffounderror

Doing a trial run for a basic MVC app. Getting NoClassDefFoundError for the class MovieDAO.

MovieDAO is in: com.library.model
The servlet MovieController is in: com.library.web

Servlet compiled successfully with correct import for the MovieDAO class.

Reproduced EXACT copy of directory structure in Tomcat 8.0/webapps/Planner/WEB-INF/classes (Planner is the project root folder). Getting NoClassDefFoundError during test run on web server.

Servlet snippet:

```
package com.library.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.library.model.*;
import com.library.model.beans.*;

public class MovieController extends HttpServlet {

     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String selectedMovie = request.getParameter("title");

        MovieDAO movieDAO = new MovieDAO();
```

XML:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"  
version="3.1">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Movie Index Page</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.library.web.MovieController</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Movie Index Page</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getPlanner</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MovieDAO snippet:

```
package com.library.model;


import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.library.model.beans.*;

public class MovieDAO {

private static final String DB_URL = 
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/planner";

//  Database credentials
private static final String USER = "Sudipto";
private static final String PASS = "sudi85";

public MovieDetails getMovieDetails(String inputMov) throws SQLException {

MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();

    try {

        //Open a connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Full Stacktrace:

```
6-Jun-2015 10:58:50.665 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Movie Index Page] in context with path [/Planner] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/library/model/MovieDAO (wrong name: MovieDAO)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
at com.library.web.MovieController.doGet(MovieController.java:16)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Obviously a misplacement of the directory/package issue. Can anyone please point out exactly what is wrong?

Comment: Can you share source for `MovieDAO` class and full stacktrace of error?

Comment: Looks like `MovieDAO` is not deployed into `WEB-INF/classes/com/library/model` where `MovieController` expects to find it

Comment: I hope you mean WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Yes I do mean WEB-INF/classes. Sorry.

Comment: MovieDAO snippet updated in query Amit.rk3.

Comment: Reimeus the MovieDAO.class file is placed in WEB-INF/classes/com/library/model. :(

Comment: @SudiptoDutta Is `MovieController` located in `WEB-INF/classes/com/library/web`?

Comment: Reimeus...yep absolutely.

Comment: It looks like your `MovieDAO` class compiled successfully with all it's dependencies in your compiler classpath. But when you deployed it on server, server runtime was not able to initialize this class properly due to some reason. One of the reason can be, the dependent classes required by `MovieDAO` which in this case may be your database connection driver class, or any other class used in this class was not in the server runtime classpath. So just verify once that you have all the required libraries for your application on your server runtime classpath.

Comment: Also lookout further in stacktrace that you don't have any nested classNotFoundException

Comment: Added the mysql jar in WEB-INF/lib. Same result. And no ClassNotFoundException either.

Comment: @SudiptoDutta : Can you share full stacktrace of error?

Comment: HI Amit.rk3, full stack trace updated in query. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `MovieDAO` class must be deployed to your applications `WEB-INF/classes` folder or within a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`. It's likely missing which leads to your `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: the .class file is under /classes.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you are? Do you have multiple Tomcat installations?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/library/model/MovieDAO (wrong name: MovieDAO)
```

breaking this error in two parts

1. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/library/model/MovieDAO`

   This tells that your `MovieController` is trying to search a class `MovieDAO`, which has package declaration `package com.library.model`
2. `(wrong name: MovieDAO)` : Basically this name is fully qualified class name of class which was found. This tells that it found class `MovieDAO` but without any package declaration.

So can you try to recompile the `MovieDAO` class and place it in correct directory under classes. Also search classes folder to see if you have placed it already in some other directory by mistake and remove it if found